# Bootstrap 3 responsiveness -- moving modules up and down in the grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to change the position of some of my modules using the Bootstrap 3 grid system.

This is the ordering I want for xs screens (pretty simple, just stacked on each other).

```
[       1       ]
[       2       ] 
[       3       ] 
[       4       ]
```

However, on sm and larger I want to move module 4 below module 1 and have module 2 and 3 to the right of module 4. Is that something that is possible with the standard Bootstrap grid?

For example (note that there are two 4 boxes just to illustrate that 4 could be larger 2 and 3.

```
[       1       ]
[    4    ][  2 ]
[    4    ][  3 ]
```

I've attempted it here: http://jsfiddle.net/5prkr2tn/1/ but I can't figure out how to move column 4 up :(. I have tried to do a few push/pulls but when I do I can't seem to get 2/3 to stack on each other when I use those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can.  You just need to split the second and third columns into their own column with their own row.   Then you can push and pull the fourth and the combined second and third columns.

http://jsfiddle.net/jxu42vst/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box-1 col-sm-12">1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="box-2 col-sm-12">2</div>
                <div class="box-3 col-sm-12">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-4 col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```